# 'Command "devenv.exe" is not valid' error in Visual Studio 2015 command window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to use the Visual Studio 2015 Command Window to in order to diff two files, using the command `devenv.exe /diff "C:\example.path" "C:\example.path"`. I received the following error:

> Command "devenv.exe" is not valid.

`devenv.exe` was missing from my computer so I repaired both my installation of (both) Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2013 to get it back.  However, I'm still getting the error when I attempt to run the `/diff` command.

What steps should I take in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you make sure that `devenv.exe`'s folder is in your `PATH` or that you're in that folder?

Comment: @mason Well, I'm not sure how to see what folder I'm in (`Command "dir" is not valid.` / `Command "ls" is not valid.`), I'm calling this command from the Visual Studio 2015 command prompt.  As for the `PATH`, devenv.exe is not in my `PATH` - it also doesn't appear to be located on my computer!  Is this called something different in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Your machine is pretty broken, you'll have to get it fixed.  Use Control Panel > System to repair the PATH environment variable, ask questions about it at superuser.com